# After stringWithContentsOfURL cookies not save in UIWebView. iOS

Tags: html, ios, cookies, save, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I want get html from url and I use:

```
NSString *URLtoHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:self.url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:URLtoHTML baseURL:nil];
```

But after this my cookies clean in UIWebView.
But if i use load request without stringWithContentsOfURL cookies save:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url]];
```

I have tried it but cookies not save too:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

How do I get a HTML and load it in UIWebView with cookies?

**UPDATE:**
If i use this case (two unrelated lines) cookies not save too:

```
NSString *URLtoHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:self.url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url]];
```

i.e. `stringWithContentsOfURL` does not save cookies. How can this be? it's funny :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION:**

First I checked the Set-Cookie which I get from the server:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.simple.com/"]];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSDictionary *fields = [HTTPResponse allHeaderFields];
    NSString *cookie = [fields valueForKey:@"Set-Cookie"]; // It is cookie
}
```

And I realized that I come value, in which cookies are disabled.
Now I first sends a request with cookies enabled:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.simple.com/"]];
[request addValue:myCustomCookies forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

**MY SOLUTION 2:**

I send request with post data

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"login=%@&passwors=%@",_login.text,_password.text];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.simple.com/login"]]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        request.timeoutInterval = 20;
        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

That's all! Good luck to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In this case - you download raw content from URL, and just showing this data in WebView. WebView just don't know about your cookies.

```
NSString *URLtoHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:self.url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:URLtoHTML baseURL:nil];
```

In this case - you create connection, but once again, download only raw data.

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

This one is closer, all you need - it's capture loaded data from WebView.

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url]];
NSString *html = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                                     @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

Comment: But in this case I have to wait for the page is loaded:
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *html = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                      @"document.body.innerHTML"];
}
It's a long time and is not suitable for me. There are any suggestions?